# Call to a member function createQueryForType() on null - exception

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I followed [Creating a first extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/latest/4-FirstExtension/Index.html) but I'm getting 500 error and:

> [Tue Mar 14 09:45:42 2017] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:
>   Call to a member function createQueryForType() on null in /var/typo3_src/typo3_src-6.2.29/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Repository.php on line 251

Server PHP 5.6 and Typo3 6.2.29

Repository code:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;

class UserRepository extends Repository {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public function getOnlineUsersAction() {
    $userRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(UserRepository::class);
    $users = $userRepository->findAll();
    // todo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Repository code:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;

class UserRepository extends Repository {
    // Remove the __construct (or add parent::__construct)
}
```

Controller code:

```
/**
 * @var MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\UserRepository
 * @inject
 */
$protected $userRepository;

public function getOnlineUsersAction() {
    $users = $this->userRepository->findAll();
    // todo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In TYPO3 v12 I had this problem when creating a repository instance from another model object via `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` and using methods on that repo.

The solution was to make the repository public in `Configuration/Services.yaml`.

Comment: This helped me very very much right now, in TYPO3 11.5 already also